# sencha app build native failed. Gives Error : <x-load-properties> does not support the <file> nested element

Tags: sencha-touch

I am using sencha touch 2.3.1 and cmd 3.1.2. But while creating buid by using command "sencha app build native", it gives error : [ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
    /path_to_app/.sencha/app/init-impl.xml:62:  does      not support the  nested element

```
$sencha app build testing
Sencha Cmd v3.1.2.342
[INF] 
[INF] init-plugin:
[INF] 
[INF] cmd-root-plugin.init-properties:
[INF] 
[INF] init-properties:
[INF] 
[INF] init-sencha-command: 
[INF] 
[INF] init:
[INF] 
[INF] app-build-impl:
[INF] 
[INF] -before-init-local:
[INF] 
[INF] -init-local:
[INF] 
[INF] -after-init-local:
[INF] 
[INF] init-local:
[INF] 
[INF] find-cmd-in-path:
[INF] 
[INF] find-cmd-in-environment:
[INF] 
[INF] find-cmd-in-shell:
[INF] 
[INF] init-cmd:
[INF]      [echo] Using Sencha Cmd from /home/bin/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.2.342 for  /path_to_app/build.xml
[INF] 
[INF] -before-init:
[INF] 
[INF] -init:
[INF] Initializing Sencha Cmd ant environment
[INF] Adding antlib taskdef for com/sencha/command/compass/ant/antlib.xml
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
/path_to_app/.sencha/app/init-impl.xml:62: <x-load-properties> does      not support the <file> nested element
```

Comment: Why don't you update your sencha cmd?

Comment: @DarinKolev Sencha app build native does not work on linux with sencha cmd 4.0

Comment: I had a lot of problems with the native packager, and now i'm using Phonegap Builder

Answer (score 1):

For this version of sencha, for creating build, "st-res" directory is required.which contains AndroidManifest.xml , nimblekit.jar. And also have to make following changes in packager.json file.

```
"androidAPILevel":"14",
"sdkPath":"/home/.android-sdk-linux"  /* path to android-sdk-linux */
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so I simply upgraded Sencha on my machine:
`$ sudo sencha upgrade`
If you'll go for that remember to close and re-open your terminal window. Then when you use the above 
command again and you should see something like:

```
Sencha Cmd v4.0.2.67
[INF] Determining the latest version of Sencha Cmd
[INF] The latest version of Sencha Cmd is 4.0.2.67
[INF] Sencha Cmd 4.0.2.67 is this version.
```

I hope this will help